# Trailing or leading slash on config/env files?

Tags: javascript

We have a config file, which gets loaded into the application. The config file, carries the base URL of the endpoints. For example:

`MY_RESOURCE_BASE_URL = "http://www.google.com/"`

Now in my code, I would do the following:

`MY_RESOURCE_BASE_URL + "search?q=1000+kittens"`

My question now is, should the `MY_RESOURCE_BASE_URL` carrie the leading slash or should it be `/search?q=1000+kittens`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a function like `concatUrl` so it won't matter at all since it'll work either if you add the leading or trailing slashes or not:

```js
const removeTrailingSlash = url => 
      url.endsWith ( '/' ) ? url.substring( 0, url.length - 1 ) : url

const removeLeadingSlash = url =>
      url.startsWith ( '/' ) ? url.substring( 1 ) : url

const concatUrl = ( partA, partB ) => 
     `${removeTrailingSlash( partA )}/${removeLeadingSlash ( partB )}`
     
const host = 'http://google.com/'
const path = '/search'

const host2 = 'http://google.com'
const path2 = 'search'

const url = concatUrl ( host, path )
const url2 = concatUrl ( host2, path2 )

console.log ( url )
console.log ( url2 )
```